# How many different arrangements of $A, B, C, D$, and $E$ which do not contain $AB$ and do not contain $BE$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many different arrangements of $A, B, C, D$, and $E$ which do not contain $AB$ and do not contain $BE$ ?

My try:

Number of $5$ letters permutations =$5!=120$

Number  of arrangements that contain $AB = 4!=24$

Number  of arrangements that contain $BE = 4!=24$

So Answer = $120-48=72$

But the answer in the book is $78$

What is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that some arrangements contain both $AB$ and $BE$, and you have subtracted them twice.

These arrangements can be thought of as arrangements of $3$ objects, $C$, $D$ and $ABE$. There are $3!$ of them, which is the $6$ that you are missing.

In general, see the [inclusion-exclusion principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)